# Problem with ListBox and DataTrigger for Chip

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate, datatrigger, material-design-in-xaml

I have a problem with `ListBoxItem` and `DataTrigger`.
I want to change the `Background` color of my `Chip` item when the chip item is clicked with the mouse.

I think the problem is in this line of code

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ListBoxItem},Path=IsSelected}"
             Value="True">
    <Setter Property="IconBackground"
            Value="#1b5eb2" />
    <Setter Property="Opacity"
            Value="1"></Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

Running my code I got a list of signals category (like in the screenshot below):

[image: Horizontal list of signal categories as Chips.]

However, when I click on them with my mouse the color of the circle does not change.

It should be working like this (when clicked):

[image: Chip with selected circle (blue).]

I tried a couple of things and checked a lot of topics about `DataTrigger`, but i can't seem to figure it out.

My .xaml view

```
<ListBox Name="SignalCategories"
         ItemsSource="{Binding DefinedSignalCategories}"
         SelectionMode="Single"
         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         BorderThickness="0">

    <!--changing default ListBoxItem to hide selection highlight-->
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <!--changing default orientation-->
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!--custom view-->
            <materialDesign:Chip Content="{Binding Name}"
                                 Margin="5"
                                 IconForeground="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueDarkForegroundBrush}">
                <materialDesign:Chip.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type materialDesign:Chip}">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                Value="0.85" />
                        <Setter Property="IconBackground"
                                Value="Gray"></Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                     Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                        Value="1" />
                                <Setter Property="IconBackground"
                                        Value="#1b5eb2">
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ListBoxItem},Path=IsSelected}"
                                         Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IconBackground"
                                        Value="#1b5eb2" />
                                <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                        Value="1"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </materialDesign:Chip.Style>
                <materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="{Binding IconName}" />
                </materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
            </materialDesign:Chip>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Does the Opacity setter work? How about the IsMouseOver Trigger?

Comment: oppacity is working , and also IsMouseOver trigger

Comment: But the IsMouseOver trigger does also not change the background, only the Opacity, right?

Comment: the IsMouseOver trigger change the collor of the background

Comment: What if you comment the IsMouseOver trigger out, so that you have only one Trigger that sets IconBackground?

Comment: i commented and check result , still not working , but i found out that if i click with right mouse button the DataTrigger is working but why not on the left mouse button like it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this does not work is that you are misusing the `Chip` control. It is a type [derived from `ButtonBase`](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/5ca41fac9a9968d7fcff21dc12deda882b41f7ff/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Chip.cs#L11), which means **it is basically a button**. It handles mouse click events, which sets the [`e.Handled` flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) of the corresponding routed event arguments to `true`. See The [Concept of Handled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-6.0#the-concept-of-handled) for reference.

> The value of Handled affects how a routed event is reported or processed as it travels further along the route. If `Handled` is `true` in the event data for a routed event, then handlers that listen for that routed event on other elements are generally no longer invoked for that particular event instance.

Consequently, the click on the `Chip` is ignored by the `ListBoxItem` and is therefore not selected. You could of course use the workaround of registering a click handler in code-behind with `handledEventsToo` as described in the article and then search up the visual tree for a `ListBoxItem` and set `IsSelected` to `true`, but I would not recommend it, since it is the wrong control to use in the first place. As `Chip` is a button, it has visual states for *Mouse Over* and *Pressed* and other states and lots of markup that you either do not need or have to override in order *to make the button act as if it was not a button*. That does not make sense.

What you can do instead is [copy the essentials of the default style](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/5ca41fac9a9968d7fcff21dc12deda882b41f7ff/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Chip.xaml#L83) for `Chip` and make a `DataTemplate` or a custom control out of it. The following data template  should work for you.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
         <Grid.Resources>
            <materialDesign:NullableToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NullableToVisibilityConverter" />
            <materialDesign:PackIcon x:Key="Icon"
                                     Kind="{Binding IconName}" />
         </Grid.Resources>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <Border CornerRadius="16"
                 Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignChipBackground}"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
         <ContentControl Grid.Column="0"
                         Content="{StaticResource Icon}"
                         Background="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}"
                         FontSize="17"
                         FontWeight="Regular"
                         IsTabStop="False"
                         Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource Icon}, Converter={StaticResource NullableToVisibilityConverter}}"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                         HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                         Height="32"
                         Width="32">
            <ContentControl.Style>
               <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidForegroundBrush}"></Setter>
                  <Style.Triggers>
                     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
                                  Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="White" />
                     </DataTrigger>
                     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ListBoxItem},Path=IsSelected}"
                                  Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="White" />
                     </DataTrigger>
                  </Style.Triggers>
               </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
            <ContentControl.Clip>
               <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="16"
                                RadiusY="16"
                                Center="16,16" />
            </ContentControl.Clip>
            <ContentControl.Template>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                  <Border x:Name="ChipBackgroundBorder"
                          Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignChipBackground}">
                     <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                       VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                  </Border>
                  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
                                  Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="ChipBackgroundBorder"
                                Property="Opacity"
                                Value="1" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ChipBackgroundBorder"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="#1b5eb2" />
                     </DataTrigger>
                     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ListBoxItem},Path=IsSelected}"
                                  Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="ChipBackgroundBorder"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="#1b5eb2" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ChipBackgroundBorder"
                                Property="Opacity"
                                Value="1" />
                     </DataTrigger>
                  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               </ControlTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Template>
         </ContentControl>
         <ContentControl Content="{Binding Name}"
                         x:Name="TextBlock"
                         IsTabStop="False"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         Margin="8 0 12 0"
                         Grid.Column="1" />
      </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

This template is almost identical to the `Chip` template for your use-case, however, you might want to consider creating your own template and simplify it drastically to fit your requirements only.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out looks like the problem is with `materialDesign:Chip`.
I've redone it without using materialDesign and now it's working correctly.

Working Code:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <!--custom view-->
    <Grid Width="auto"
          Height="30"
          x:Name="grid1"
          Margin="10">
        <Border BorderBrush="Transparent"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Background="#939393"
                Panel.ZIndex="1000"
                BorderThickness="0"
                CornerRadius="30"
                Width="30"
                Height="30"
                x:Name="BorderCircle">
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="{Binding IconName}"
                                     Margin="5"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                     Foreground="White" />
        </Border>
        <Border Background="#efefef"
                BorderThickness="0"
                CornerRadius="15"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Margin="10 0 0 0">

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="25 0 10 0" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
                     Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="BorderCircle"
                    Property="Background"
                    Value="#1b5eb2" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Output:
[image]